# Later and after used in a same sentence

Tags: conjunctions

Which of the sentences below  is correct

1. Ram called me 2 days later after going Home.
   2.Ram called me 2 days after going Home.

Comment: In the first example, ***2 days later*** is relative to *current narrative reference time* (as established by preceding text / earlier conversation, which we don't have), and ***after*** is relative to *when Ram went home*. In the second one the "narrative reference time" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ram called me 2 days later, after going Home.

Clearly, "later" and "after" are relative to two different things. We use "later" when following on from some other statement about an established time, so I would presume that this sentence followed details of some time spent with Ram away from his home.

> *For example*:
> Ram and I spent all of Saturday together. He called me two days later, after going home.

This would mean that the phone call occurred on Monday - two days after they spent the day together on the Saturday. Ram could have gone home *any time in-between* - maybe later on the Saturday, maybe on Sunday.

2. Ram called me 2 days after going home.

This is also correct, but it doesn't give us any time frame, unless you had previously stated when Ram went home. If we know when he went home, we can work out when he called - or vice versa.